# Bitwise in a client - server scenario miscalculating

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, actionscript-3, bit-shift, bitwise-or

I have been tasked with creating a server for a client. I have all of the clients' code, so using it, I must create a server.

The client has a particular piece of code in a function called `readInt(num1)`; `return num1 << 24 | num1 << 16 | num1 << 8 | num1`, which is called every time the client expects a `type = int` in the data received from a packet, and I just can't haggle with it.

I tried what comes to mind first - just reverse it, right? If the int needs to be 3, do `3 >> 24`, but no yield.

My mind doesn't work well mathematically, and I'm not a good problem solver, so if I want, say `3` on the server to read as `3` on the client, what formula would I use server-side to achieve this?

The client is in Adobe ActionScript 3, and the server in Python 2.7.12.

Comment: There is not enough info to help you. Show how you make the `3` in Python & how you read into AS3... Are the packets being received into some AS3 byteArray? If yes, then why not just use something like `num1 = myBytes.readUnsignedInteger();`? Since an Integer type uses 4 bytes you go the expected starting `.position` of those 4 bytes to read within the total bytes length of your packet. Anyways your example of 3 would use  just one byte so its enough to use `num1 = myBytes.readByte();`. Check the **AS3 ByteArray API** in online docs...

Comment: @VC.One I just use int(3) in Python. I believe they are being inserted into a bytearray in AS3, but I will double check, however, I only have read access to the AS code, yet write access to the Python code. The Python code must create an integer which is then sent to the AS client. Additionally, any expieremnts I do of reversal, don't. Are you suggesting I send a struct'D int from Python? I'm not sure if the client will accept it, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

the only way i know, is sending negative number from server for getting a same result, otherwise not possible to reversing it through server (i guess)